# C# winforms , Subtracting/adding sum to int in a class from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a school project with c# winforms visual studio. The software has balance anlytics etc.
I have deposit money that "should subtract CryptoMoney and add money to Walletmoney".
I can't understand why instead of subtracting and adding money , it's just settings the money amount instead of adding it. hope you understand more by code..
Thank you!!!

```cs
private void DepositBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = Int32.Parse(textBoxDeposit.Text); // textbox that user can enter amount he want.

    if (obj.Cryptomoney >= num)
    {
        obj.SubtractCryptoMoney(num);
        MessageBox.Show(obj.Cryptomoney.ToString());
        obj.AddWalletMoney(num);
        MessageBox.Show(obj.Walletmoney.ToString());

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

this is the internal class

```cs
internal class Money
{
    // all money that set here, is set by admin for videos . The set will happen in login form...
    
    int CryptoMoney;    // Crypto Wallet money
    int WalletMoney;   //  Software Money
    int EarnedMoney;  //   Earned Money in last 30 days... 
   
    public Money(int cryptoMoney, int walletMoney, int earnedMoney)
    {
        CryptoMoney = cryptoMoney;
        WalletMoney = walletMoney;
        Earnedmoney = earnedMoney;
    }
    public int Earnedmoney
    {
        get { return EarnedMoney; }
        set { EarnedMoney = value; }
    }
    public int Cryptomoney
    {
        get { return EarnedMoney; }
        set { EarnedMoney = value; }
    }
    public int Walletmoney
    {
        get { return EarnedMoney; }
        set { EarnedMoney = value; }
    }
```

```cs
// these are the functions i use when pressing on deposit btn:

public int SubtractCryptoMoney(int num) { Cryptomoney -= num; return Cryptomoney; }
public int SubtractWalletMoney(int num) { Walletmoney -= num; return Walletmoney; }
public int AddCryptoMoney(int num) { Cryptomoney += num; return Cryptomoney; }
public int AddWalletMoney(int num) { Walletmoney += num; return Walletmoney; }
```

Comment: You can't just deposit money in the bank if you do not have the money.  Where is the money coming from?  You project is getting CyptoMoney and depositing the CyptoMoney into the Wallet Money.  You can't just deposit money into the Wallet if you do not have any money.

Comment: In addition to the answer from @Suryateja KONDLA, you should consider adjusting your deposit button logic to use `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Int32.Parse`. Presently, your code will throw `System.FormatException` if non-numeric input is provided in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your `Money class`, both `Cryptomoney` and `Walletmoney` properties are incorrectly mapped to the `EarnedMoney` field. They should be linked to their respective fields, `CryptoMoney` and `WalletMoney`. This changes to `Cryptomoney` and `Walletmoney` are affecting `EarnedMoney` instead.

```
public int Cryptomoney
{
    get { return CryptoMoney; } // Return the correct field
    set { CryptoMoney = value; } // Set the correct field
}

public int Walletmoney
{
    get { return WalletMoney; } // Return the correct field
    set { WalletMoney = value; } // Set the correct field
}
```